# Robot Framework , inheriting multiple mixins

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, mixins, pageobjects

I work on a project with robot framework , pageobject library ,selenium2library.
**I couldn't find a way to use multiple mixins on a page object.**
I want to use two mixins with LoginPage.
MainNavigation works but HeaderMixin doesn't work.
My suite setup is login on every tests so I need to use mixins on that LoginPage
How to use more than one mixin on a page object ?

this is my LoginPage object :

```
class LoginPage(MainNavigation, HeaderMixin, PageObject):
    """LoginPage baseclass"""

    PAGE_URL = "/user/login"
    PAGE_TITLE = "Title"

    _locators = {
            "username": 'id=login_email',
            "password": 'id=login_password',
            "button": "id=login"
    }
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. "doesn't work" just isn't enough information to go on. It would also help to show which page object library you're using. I'm assuming https://github.com/boakley/robotframework-pageobjectlibrary, but you should include that information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special you need to do to use multiple mixins -- just create a python class with any new keywords that you want, and include the mixins when defining the class.

For example, consider the following two mixin classes:

```
class MainNavigation():
    def main_nav_keyword(self):
        pass

class HeaderMixin():
    def header_keyword(self):
        pass
```

You can use these mixins in your `LoginPage` class:

```
class LoginPage(MainNavigation, HeaderMixin, PageObject):
    ...
```

Within a class that uses the `LoginPage`, you can now access the navigation keywords and header keywords as if they were part of the page:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    go to page  LoginPage
    the current page should be  LoginPage
    main nav keyword
    header keyword
```

Comment: my first page is LoginPage and I tried like you said before but it doesn't work

Comment: @KaanSan: "doesn't work" is a useless phrase. You must be getting some sort of error or unexpected behavior. You need to edit your question to include the error or unexpected behavior.